# Get date closest to today in PHP from database

Tags: php, mysql, date, getdate

**UPDATE**

I'm making a backend of a website. The mean point of the website is to give a clear overview to the visitors when and what activities we are organizing.
So I filled the database with all kinds of activities. Every activity has a date, a name and some other information.

It's quite obvious the visitors aren't helped by showing the activities in the past, so I only want them to show the forthcoming activities. And to save myself a lot of work, it would be nice to do PHP/MySQL all the work and showing the visitors only the 2 next events.

Can you advise me a MySQL function to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Erm. PHP doesn't have direct access to *your database*. This means you don't use a PHP function to get something from MySQL. Can you give this a bit more thought and rephrase?

Comment: When you say closest to today, are you talking about activites before today, after today (assuming you have activities in the future), or both?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: yeah right, my bad. I sure meant MySQL of course. I'm not that skilled in PHP, so I was just wondering. Do you get what I'm trying to accomplish? Or do you need more information?

Comment: @d.syph.3r I do mean activities before today. The database is filled with activities both past and future. The ones in the past are just for our information, the ones in the future are for the visitors. So I only want to display the ones in the future.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru I don't have enough information to know for sure what you want. I can only guess. You should edit the question and add more details.

Comment: @Michiel, update your question... you don't want the closest date, you want the closest future date...

Comment: @Alin @Jacob, Question updated. I hope it's more clear now. If not, please let me know

Comment: @Michiel You don't have a certain *function*. You have to do your own query. For what you want is quite simple. See my updated answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some advice:

Select the closest 2 events before the current moment and the closest 2 after the current moment.

```
(SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE `time` < NOW()
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE `time` > NOW()
ORDER BY `time` ASC
LIMIT 2)
```

At this point you'll have at most 4 events in PHP. But you only need 2. The closest 2. To find out which are the closest you make use of [`strtotime`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and check the differences between the timestamps of the events and the current timestamp that you can get by calling `time()`. After that you keep only the 2 closest events.

*Note that this can be achieved directly from MySQL, but it's harder that way.*

---

**@Latest update. It's sufficient to read this if you don't want to know more.**

Just use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE `time` > NOW()
ORDER BY `time` ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: This one did the trick! Thanks a lot. It is good performance-wise if I have like 2,000 activities?

Comment: At 2000 it doesn't matter that much. But just to be on the safe side add an index on the `time` column.

Comment: Will do :) Thanks! (Why doesn't it matter with 2000. Does it when there are like 5 of them?)

Comment: @Michiel I meant it doesn't matter that much because 2000 is not a very large number.

Comment: I think u can use UNION ALL in thie case, which u should as it's more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [`ABS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)...

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`)) LIMIT 2
```

---

From the updated question only future activities are to be considered... So...

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `date` > NOW() ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Quick solution. But bad performance-wise if there are too many events. You can't add an index on an expression like that, but you can add it on the time column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE `date` > '.$today.' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 2';
```

`$today` depends on your `date` column type.

Comment: Changing PHP's $today to MySQL's NOW() will stop SQL injection, and still always provide relevant information regardless of the 'date' column type.

Comment: Only if 'today' is real today :)